# return a json response from a class method in flask

Tags: python, class, flask, return

I have a class that handles changes in the DB with a couple of methods, In each method, I am doing some sort of validation to the data to check if it's acceptable, and if not it will return a `jsonfiy` response with an error and status code:

```
class ChangeData():
# more code...
    def change_data(self, new_data):

        if new_data not valid:
            print({"error": "first name can only contain latters"})# will print if not valid
            return jsonify({"error":
                            "can't change the data"}), 400

        else:
            #change the data
```

I was expecting that if the data is not valid it will return to the frontend the jsonfiy error message but although the print works the frontend isn't receiving the jsonfiy error its receiving the jsonfiy success message no matter if the data is valid or not.

```
@app.route("/change", methods=["POST"])
def change_user_data():

    data = request.form

    update_data = ChangeData()

    new_data = data.get("new_data", None)


    if new_data:
        update_data.change_data(new_data)
    

    return jsonfiy({"sucsees": "the data as been changed"}), 200
```

One way I can solve it is by returning `False` from the `change_data` method if the data is not valid and `True` if it is, and based on that return a jsonfiy from the "/change" route, but I don't like this solution, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Return from a inner method returns to caller, not all the way up. return your response back to flask like `return update_data.change_data(new_data)`

Comment: But if I have more code under the `if new_data:` then it will not be executed or am I missing something?

Comment: No it will not. As the answer below, its not a good practice to create the http response from lower layers. Always return the response content from data layers, and prepare your response from service layers.

Comment: Ok good to know that, I will give "NoCommandLine" answer a try when I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your calling code doesn't expect a return so your error is not being 'captured' on return from the function

```
if new_data:
        update_data.change_data(new_data)
```

2. Even if your calling code expected a return value, you're not checking if an error occurred before returning an output to the client. Your code simply does

```
return jsonfiy({"success": "the data as been changed"}), 200
```

3. One possible solution is to put your calling code within a try except block and raise an exception from the callee. Something like this (this is a rough outline and you have to flesh it out)

```
class ChangeData():
    def change_data(self, new_data):

        if new_data not valid:
            print({"error": "first name can only contain letters"})
            raise Exception("first name can only contain letters")
```

```
@app.route("/change", methods=["POST"])
def change_user_data():

    data = request.form
    update_data = ChangeData()
    new_data = data.get("new_data", None)

    try:
        if new_data:
            update_data.change_data(new_data)
        return jsonfiy({"sucsees": "the data as been changed"}), 200

    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "can't change the data"}), 400
```

Comment: It looks like a nice solution I will give it a try when I am at work again, the only change I will make is to give the "error" the text of the Exception